# Javascript Assert object chain

Tags: javascript, object, assert

I have objects with many sub attributes and objects in Javascript.

So some lines of my code look like this:

```
  obj.eventOfType = (el.openSocial && el.openSocial.embed && el.openSocial.embed.context &&
                    el.openSocial.embed.context.openSocial && el.openSocial.embed.context.openSocial.connections &&
                    el.openSocial.embed.context.openSocial.connections.generator && el.openSocial.embed.context.openSocial.connections.generator.displayName) ?
                el.openSocial.embed.context.openSocial.connections.generator && el.openSocial.embed.context.openSocial.connections.generator.displayName || "";
```

Does not look very nice.. So I thought about a function and wrote this:

```
    /**
     * assert path exists as subobject chain within obj
     * 
     * @param obj {object} the object to search for <code>path</code> in
     * @param path {String} the path to search within <code>obj</code>. oatgh must not start wirth the object itself.
     * @return {boolean} whether <code>path</code> exists within <code>obj</code> or not
     * example: to check if the windows document body has a fist item element you would use
     * if (assertChain(window, "document.body.firstChild")) {}
     * instead of 
     * if (window && window.document && window.document.body && window.document.body.firstChild) {}
     */
    function assertChain(obj, path) {
        var o = obj,
            ret = ("object" === $.type(obj) && "string" === $.type(path));

        if (ret) {
            $(path.split(".") || {}).each(function(ignore, value) {
                ret = value in o;
                if (ret) {
                    o = o[value];
                }
                return ret;
            });
        }
        return ret;
    }

    var t = assertChain(dataItem, "dataItem.openSocial.embed.context.connectionsContentUrl") && dataItem.openSocial.embed.context.connectionsContentUrl;

    dataItem.xcc = dataItem.xcc || {}; //Access it
```

So at Stackoverflow, I found this:

```
var isDefined = function(value, path) {
  path.split('.').forEach(function(key) { value = value && value[key]; });
  return (typeof value != 'undefined' && value !== null);
};

var t = {a: {a1: 33, a12: {aa1d: 444, cc: 3}}, b: 00};

var results = '';
['a.a12.cc', 'a.a1.cc'].forEach(function(path) {
    results += 't[' + path + '] = ' + isDefined(t, path) + '\n';
});

document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('pre')).textContent = results;
```

Which way is the best?

Comment: What do you mean by "best"?

Comment: I must say, that is some ternary statement.

Comment: Though the question is unclear, you can use `try catch`. `var a=null; try{a=el.openSocial.embed.context.openSocial.connections.generator.displayName} catch(ex){a=''}`. Also, if the objective is just to get improvements, [CodeReviews](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is the right place for it.

Answer (score 0):

I have an little improvement for code above.

My function returns an given path property, or `undefined`. What's more, it stops iteration when `undefined` is found (forEach will keep iterating untill the end of path array)

```js
const assertProperty = (object, path) => {
  if(typeof object !== 'object' || typeof path !== 'string')
    return
    
  let scrap = object
  
  path.split('.').every((part) => scrap = scrap[part])
  
  return scrap
}

let test = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: {
        d : {
          e: {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(assertProperty(test, 'a.b.c.d'))

console.log(assertProperty(test, 'a.b.c.d.e.f.g'))
```

In Your code, You can use it like :

```
var displayName = assertProperty(el, 'openSocial.embed.context.openSocial.connections.generator.displayName') || ''
```